# How do I fix messages frozen by exim due to a typo in recipient?

Tags: email-server, exim

I have a couple of frozen messages in my exim queue which have a misspelled recipient, e.g. `reciepint@domain.tld` instead of `recipient@domain.tld`.

Apparently they could be fixed by correcting the recipient and unfreezing them.

How can I do this with exim? Or, instead, how could I deliver a frozen message to a different address manually?

Comment: Why are they frozen? If the recipient was misspelled, they should have been rejected by the remote SMTP server on the first delivery attempt, and already bounced back to the sender.

Answer (score 0):

Exim will try to deliver that messages for week or so and then drop them and send the notification about fail to the sender. So in general you need no manual intervention to the process.

Also you can remove all that messages from the queue by the command like that:

```
grep -l "reciepint@domain.tld" /var/spool/exim/msglog | xargs exim -Mrm
```

Here `/var/spool/exim/msglog` is the path to the directory exim stored logs for undelivered messages. It can be different for your system. An option `-l` is `dash-ell` not the `dash-one`.

`exim -Mrm <MESSAGEID>` is the native command for purging the message from the queue.